# How to cancel Axios request in react redux with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am working in React with Redux. I have written the action called products to fetch the product details from backend using Axios. In that, I used cancel token to cancel the HTTP request if the user navigates to another page during the process.

But still, I got the error in the console like below when I navigate to another page.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

When I navigate to the same product page to fetch the data, the request goes to the catch block to throw the error. I used the below code to dispatch the action.

product.js as action

```
const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
const fetchProducts = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get("myurl", {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      });

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong, while fetching the products!");
      }

      dispatch({ type: GET_PRODUCTS, products: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
      if (Axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };
};

const cancelRequest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    if (source !== typeof undefined) {
      source.cancel("Operation canceled by the user.");
      dispatch({ type: CANCEL_REQUEST, message: "Request canceled by user!" });
    }
  };
};
```

component file:

```
const loadProducts = useCallback(async () => {
  setError(null);
  try {
    await dispatch(productActions.fetchProducts());
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
  }
}, [dispatch, setError]);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  loadProducts().then(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  });

  return () => {
    dispatch(productActions.cancelRequest());
  };
}, [dispatch, loadProducts, setIsLoading]);
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cancelling the request on `unmount`. After cancellation, you end up in the catch block of `loadProducts`. Over there, you are setting the state `setError(...)`. Hence you are getting the error as you are trying to set state on unmounted component.

To solve the issue, simply don't set the state in catch block. As per the your code, there don't seem to be any need of setting error state. If you want you can get it from the store (as the reducer `CANCEL_REQUEST` should have the message)

```js
const loadProducts = useCallback(async () => {
  setError(null);
  try {
    await dispatch(productActions.fetchProducts());
  } catch (err) {
    //setError(err.message); //<----- this is the issue, remove this line
  }
}, [dispatch, setError]);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  loadProducts().then(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  });

  return () => {
    dispatch(productActions.cancelRequest());
  };
}, [dispatch, loadProducts, setIsLoading]);
```

**Edit** Based on comments:

Make following changes, it works properly.

- put `then` block first and then the `catch` block
- move setting state in promise-catch block (not try catch)
- Also, there is no need of try/catch block as we are handling `setError` in promise-catch block

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-and-suspense-egghead-playlist-15gz3?file=/src/useAxiosFetch.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
const useAxiosFetch = url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let source = axios.CancelToken.source()
    setLoading(true)
    axios
      .get(url, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      })
      .then(a => {
        console.log('here')
        setData(a)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(function(thrown) {
        //put catch after then
        if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
          console.log(`request cancelled:${thrown.message}`)
        } else {
          console.log('another error happened')
          setData(null)
          setError(thrown)
        }
        // throw (thrown)
      })

    if (source) {
      console.log('source defined')
    } else {
      console.log('source NOT defined')
    }

    return function() {
      console.log('cleanup of useAxiosFetch called')
      if (source) {
        console.log('source in cleanup exists')
      } else {
        source.log('source in cleanup DOES NOT exist')
      }
      source.cancel('Cancelling in cleanup')
    }
  }, [])

  return {data, loading, error}
}
```

Comment: Still, it is not worked. I removed the setError method. But no luck, I got same error.

Comment: Whenever I navigate to the same page to fetch the data, it goes to the catch block in action. catch (err) {
      if (Axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }

Comment: hi - it should work... can you share your full code if possible (codesandbox or github) ... also [see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861916/canceling-an-axios-rest-call-in-react-hooks-useeffects-cleanup-failing)

Comment: Hi, Please find the GitHub path to find the source. https://github.com/spvjebaraj/react-redux-axios-cancel

Comment: I have also tested this scenario in code sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/8lzwl57nr8?file=/src/index.js. It also fails.

Comment: sorry for delay - i was busy --- updated the answer now ... hope all good now..

Comment: Thanks, gdh. It is working fine without any issues if I use it in the component. How to run this code from reducer?

Comment: glad to hear it is working ... reg reducer, could you please raise a new qn as your current issue is resolved and it is slightly different topic... asking good qns is good for your reputations as well and it catches eyes of others